# Current dir in Get-Location -Stack

Tags: powershell-2.0

Trying to determine if the `$pwd` is in Powershell's directory stack.

I"m getting the stack like this:

```
$stack = Get-Location -Stack
```

and trying to search like this:
    $found = $stack | Select-String "$pwd"

I have tried single quote, double quote, tried `'$pwd.ProviderPath'`.

Is there a better filter than `Select-String` for this?  Am I using `Select-String` incorrectly?  Thanks for any insights...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Simple Match.

```
get-location -stack |select-string -SimpleMatch "$pwd"
```